# simple map in C

Tags: c, hash-map

I wrote a simple map structure in C:

**map.c**

```
#include <assert.h>

#include "map.h"

void map_init(Map *m, int item_len)
{
    assert(item_len > 0);
    m->item_len = item_len;
    m->cap = 0;
    m->cnt = 0;
    m->buf = NULL;
    m->cmpfunc = NULL;
}

int map_setcap(Map *m, int cap)
{
    if (cap < m->cap)
        return 1;
    if (cap > m->cap)
    {
        void *buf = realloc(m->buf, cap * m->item_len);
        if (buf == NULL)
            return -1;
        m->cap = cap;
        m->buf = buf;
    }
    return 0;
}

int map_walk(Map *m, map_iter iter)
{
    int rc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m->cnt; i++)
    {
        rc = iter((char *)m->buf + i * m->item_len, m->item_len);
        if (rc != 0)
            break;
    }
    return rc;
}

void *map_find(Map *m, void *key, int *idx)
{
    if (m->cmpfunc == NULL)
        m->cmpfunc = memcmp;
    int first = 0;
    int last = m->cnt - 1;
    int middle = (first + last) / 2;
    void *ptr = NULL;
    while (first <= last)
    {
        void *haystack = (char *)m->buf + m->item_len * middle;
        int rc = m->cmpfunc(haystack, key, m->item_len);
        if (rc == 0)
        {
            ptr = haystack;
            break;
        }
        if (rc < 0)
            first = middle + 1;
        else
            last = middle - 1;
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
    }
    if (idx != NULL)
        *idx = (ptr == NULL) ? ((last < 0) ? 0 : middle + 1) : middle;
    return ptr;
}

void *map_find_addr(Map *m, void *key, int *idx)
{
    return map_find(m, &key, idx);
}

int map_add(Map *m, void *item)
{
    int idx;
    char *p = map_find(m, item, &idx);
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(p, item, m->item_len);
        return 1;
    }
    if (m->cap == m->cnt)
    {
        void *buf = realloc(m->buf, (m->cap + 1) * m->item_len);
        if (buf == NULL)
            return -1;
        m->cap++;
        m->buf = buf;
    }
    p = (char *)m->buf + m->item_len * idx;
    if (m->cnt > idx)
        memmove(p + m->item_len, p, (m->cnt - idx) * m->item_len);
    memcpy(p, item, m->item_len);
    m->cnt++;
    return 0;
}

int map_add_addr(Map *m, void *item)
{
    return map_add(m, &item);
}

int map_del(Map *m, void *item)
{
    int idx;
    char *p = map_find(m, item, &idx);
    if (p == NULL)
        return 0;
    memmove(p, p + m->item_len, (m->cnt - idx - 1) * m->item_len);
    m->cnt--;
    return 1;
}

int map_del_addr(Map *m, void *item)
{
    return map_del(m, &item);
}

void map_free(Map *m)
{
    free(m->buf);
    m->buf = NULL;
    m->cnt = 0;
    m->cap = 0;
}

int map_cmpstr(const void *haystack, const void *needle, size_t len)
{
    char *ptr1 = *(char **)haystack;
    char *ptr2 = *(char **)needle;
    return strcmp(ptr1, ptr2);
}
```

**map.h**

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int (*map_iter)(const void *, size_t);
typedef int (*map_cmp)(const void *, const void *, size_t);

typedef struct
{
    int item_len; //length of each item
    int cnt;      //item count
    int cap;      //capacity of buf in term of # of items
    void *buf;
    map_cmp cmpfunc;
} Map;

void map_init(Map *m, int item_len);

//0=success; 1=cap too small; -1=out-of-memory
int map_setcap(Map *m, int cap);

//NULL=not found; otherwise pointer to item
//idx: if not NULL, store position of item found/to insert
void *map_find(Map *m, void *key, int *idx);
void *map_find_addr(Map *m, void *key, int *idx);

//0=inserted; 1=updated; -1=out-of-memory
int map_add(Map *m, void *item);
int map_add_addr(Map *m, void *item);

//0=not found; 1=deleted
int map_del(Map *m, void *item);
int map_del_addr(Map *m, void *item);

int map_walk(Map *m, map_iter iter);

void map_free(Map *m);

int map_cmpstr(const void *haystack, const void *needle, size_t len);

#endif
```

**test_map.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "map.h"

void find(Map *m, void *key)
{
    char *ptr = map_find(m, key, NULL);
    if (ptr == NULL)
        printf("%c not found\n", *(char *)key);
    else
        printf("found: %c\n", *ptr);
}

void show(Map *m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m->cnt; i++)
        printf("%c", *(char *)(m->buf + i));
    printf("\n");
}

int walk(const void *buf, size_t len)
{
    char c = ((char *)buf)[0];
    if (strchr("aeiou", c))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int walkstr(const void *buf, size_t len)
{
    printf("has: %s\n", *(char **)buf);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Map m;
    map_init(&m, 1);
    map_setcap(&m, 10);
    printf("inserting to map...\n");
    char buf[7] = "kctepi";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buf); i++)
        map_add(&m, buf + i);
    show(&m);
    printf("look for vowels in map...\n");
    if (map_walk(&m, walk))
        printf("found vowel letter\n");
    else
        printf("vowel letter not found\n");
    printf("find items in map...\n");
    char *needle = "hithere";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(needle); i++)
        find(&m, needle + i);
    printf("delete item from map...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(needle); i++)
        if (map_del(&m, needle + i))
            printf("%c deleted\n", *(char *)(needle + i));
        else
            printf("%c not found\n", *(char *)(needle + i));
    printf("look for vowels in map (again)...\n");
    if (map_walk(&m, walk))
        printf("found vowel letter\n");
    else
        printf("vowel letter not found\n");
    show(&m);
    map_free(&m);
    printf("now test string map...\n");
    map_init(&m, sizeof(char *));
    m.cmpfunc = map_cmpstr;
    map_add_addr(&m, "a");
    map_add_addr(&m, "ab");
    map_add_addr(&m, "abcdefghi");
    map_add_addr(&m, "d");
    map_add_addr(&m, "de");
    map_add_addr(&m, "def");
    map_del_addr(&m, "de");
    map_del_addr(&m, "de"); //delete again has no effect
    map_add_addr(&m, "abc");
    int idx;
    char **p = map_find_addr(&m, "abc", &idx);
    if (p == NULL)
        printf("abc not found\n");
    else
        printf("found %s, idx=%d\n", *p, idx);
    p = map_find_addr(&m, "abcd", NULL);
    if (p == NULL)
        printf("abcd not found\n");
    else
        printf("found: %s, idx=%d\n", *p, idx);
    printf("map has %d items\n", m.cnt);
    map_walk(&m, walkstr);
    map_free(&m);
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there any bugs or improvements?
2. I simply used sorted dynamic array to store the data, how about performance and scalability of the design?
3. Is there any better algorithm to set capacity of the buffer?

Thanks for any critics and suggestions.

Comment: You return various error codes in map.c and then don't check them in test_map.c.  Could be as easy as wrapping each call with a macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, a  nicely laid our design and implementation.

1. Is there any bugs or improvements?

**`int` vs. `size_t`**

Rather than use `int`, consider `size_t` for lengths, `.cap` and sizing.  It is the type that supports all array indexing, unlike `int`.

Even if stuck on using `int`, consider below.  As `int`, the product can overflow as `int`, but not `size_t`.

```
// realloc(m->buf, (m->cap + 1) * m->item_len);
realloc(m->buf, (size_t)(m->cap + 1) * m->item_len);
```

**Information hiding**

Rather than user code using `m->cnt`, consider a helper function `map_count(m)`, could even be `inline`.

The [goal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) is for user code to not *know* about the details and members of `map`.

**Deeper Information hiding**

Allocate `map` as part of the initialization.  Then only `map*` needed in `map.h` and the entire `map` structure is hidden in map.c

**`NULL` valid to add?**

Since `NULL` is return in getting, perhaps test if `data == NULL` on adding.

```
assert(data);
```

**include order**

To test that `map.h` does not rely on any *includes*, let `map.h` be first in map.c

```
// #include <assert.h>
#include "map.h"
#include <assert.h>
```

**map.h only include what is needed for map.h**

```
#include <stddef.h>
//#include <stdbool.h>
//#include <stdint.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <string.h>
```

**Documentation**

Often a user only has access or cares about the.h file.  Add info there to describe the functions and the overall goals.

**`const`**

`map_find(Map *m, void *key, int *idx)` shouldn't modify the `map` structure.

```
// void *map_find(Map *m, void *key, int *idx) {
void *map_find(cont Map *m, void *key, int *idx) {

  // if (m->cmpfunc == NULL) m->cmpfunc = memcmp;
  map_cmp cmpfunc = (m->cmpfunc == NULL) ? memcmp : m->cmpfunc;
  // or put m->cmpfunc = memcmp in map_init()
```

**`void *` vs. `char *`**

Using `char *` has no disadvantages here and reduces casting.

```
 //void *buf;  
 char *buf;
```

**Avoid overflow**

For large values...

```
// int middle = (first + last) / 2;
int middle = first + (last - first) / 2;
```

2. I simply used sorted dynamic array to store the data, how about performance and scalability of the design?

**scalability**

See above discussion about `size_t` vs. `int`.

3. Is there any better algorithm to set capacity of the buffer?

**`realloc()`**

Rather than increasing the `cap` by 1, I'd double it.

**Other**

Need to think on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments.   There is one problem.   I moved the struct into map.c, and in map.h: `typedef struct Map Map;`,  then, there is a compiling error saying `error: storage size of ‘m’ isn’t known` when declaring the variable in test_map.c: `Map m`.

Comment: the above problem is solved by only use `Map *` , i.e. change map_init to `Map *map_init(...)`

Comment: @xrfang Yes, good work.  Public only sees `Map*`.